# How to show images in horizontal collection view inside tableview swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I want to show image using sdWebImage to an image inside collectionView Cell which is inside tableView cell. How to do it ?
I have array of images and I want to show it in collection view cell
this is what I tried

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


if let imgUrl = (myArray[indexPath.row] as? String)
        {
            //myArray = image array
            if let url = URL(string: imgUrl as! String) {
                    cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "product.png"), options: .lowPriority)

                }
            }
}
```

I already set

```
func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate, forRow row: Int) {
       collectionVIew.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
       collectionVIew.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
       collectionVIew.tag = row
       collectionVIew.reloadData()
   }
```

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DashboardTableViewCell") as! DashboardTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.selectedIP = indexPath
        cell.collectionVIew.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.collectionVIew.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
```

But I don't know how to show images inside collection view in particular tableview section.
Please Help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the image not showing? is the delegate not being called?

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma - images are showing but first 3-4 images shown everywhere in each section and collection cell

Comment: You have to rearrange your data structure, where it would be an array of arrays. So, an array for number of cells for tableview, and each array would have an array for number of cells for collectionView.

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma - I don't get it.what do u want to say?

Comment: What dataSource array are you using? And where have you added the collectionView dataSource methods?

Comment: @PGDev - I added the collectionView dataSource methods inside tableviewcell.

Comment: How do you pass data to `myArray`? in the `tableViewCell` (considering your `cellforrow...` is inside the tableViewCell)

Answer (score 0):

Set Collection view Deleagte and dataSource inside the table view cellforRow method

```
collectionview.delegae = self
collectionview.datasource = self
```

Comment: If that was the issue, the cells won't appear in the collectionView at first place. But according to OP he can see the images in the collectionView. Its just that they are repeating. So, I don't think this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mention by @AjinkyaSharma You have to rearrange your data structure, where it would be an array of arrays.

```
let myImages: [[String]] = [
    ["image_url_0_0", "image_url_0_1", "image_url_0_2", "image_url_0_3"],
    ["image_url_1_0", "image_url_1_1", "image_url_1_2"],
    ["image_url_2_0", "image_url_2_1", "image_url_2_2", "image_url_2_3", "image_url_2_4"],
    ["image_url_3_0", "image_url_3_1"]
]
```

Now you tableview `cellForRowAt` will set the required array of images for collectionView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myImages.size
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DashboardTableViewCell") as! DashboardTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.selectedIP = indexPath
    cell.collectionVIew.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.myArray = myImages[indexPath.row]
    cell.collectionVIew.reloadData()
    return cell
}
```

Now you need to use your myArray array to display your collectionView cells

Comment: how should I write in CollectionView(cellforrow:) , if let imgUrl = (myArray[indexPath.row] as? String)
             {
            //myArray = image array
            if let url = URL(string: imgUrl as! String) {
                    cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "product.png"), options: .lowPriority)

                }
            } this doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

One of your url is not able to satisfy if let condition. Set default image to nil to make sure not to show any previous data.
Try This:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        cell.imgView.image = nil  // set default image nil 

        if let imgUrl = (myArray[indexPath.row] as? String)
             {
            //myArray = image array
            if let url = URL(string: imgUrl as! String) {
                    cell.imgView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "product.png"), options: .lowPriority)

                }
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try With Below Code

```
class YourCustomizeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  let collectionView: CollectionView
   ...
   }

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HorizontalSlideCell", for: indexPath) as! YourCustomizeTableViewCell
cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row

return cell
}

 ...

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "InnerCollectionViewCell",
                                          for: indexPath as IndexPath)


   //indexPath.section is the collectionview section index but needs to be its parent tableview section's index. How do I get it? 
cellCharLabel?.text = 

Languages.sharedInstance.alphabets[collectionView.tag].set[indexPath.row].char
...
return cell
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate<D:UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate>(datasourcedelegate : D, forRow row:Int){
    collectionVIew.delegate = datasourcedelegate
    collectionVIew.dataSource = datasourcedelegate
    collectionVIew.tag = row
    collectionVIew.isPagingEnabled = row == 0 ? false : true
    collectionVIew.accessibilityHint = row == 0 ? "category" : "offers"
    collectionVIew.reloadData()
} 


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell,  forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)  

     guard let cell = cell as? DashboardTableViewCell else {
            return
        }

    cell.setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(datasourcedelegate: self, forRow: indexPath.section)

}

extension HomeViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PopularCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? PopularCollectionViewCell else {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }
    cell.backgroundColor = .clear
    cell.setValue(data: popularItemList[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
}

 extension HomeViewController : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width:120, height: itemWidth + 82)
}
}
```